# translating algorithm for C++ nested while loop diamond pattern

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is my homework problem for C++:

The following algorithm is a solution to a problem that uses nested loops to display a diamond pattern.   Translate the algorithm below in to a C++ program.  Build, run and test the program.

**Algorithm Solution:**

Start

```
Declare numRows as constant integer = 7
Declare maxPlus as constant integer = 7
Declare numSpaces as integer
Declare numPluses as integer
Declare row as integer
Declare space as integer
Declare plus as integer

Set row = 1

Repeat while row >= 1 AND row <= numRows
    Set numPluses = 2 * row - 1
    if(numPluses > maxPlus) then
        Set numPluses = 14 - numPluses
    endif

    Set numSpaces = (maxPlus - numPluses) / 2

    Set space = 1
    Repeat while space >= 1 AND space <= numSpaces
        Display( ' ')
        Set space = space + 1
    End Repeat

    Set plus = 1
    Repeat while plus >= 1 AND plus <= numPluses
        Display( '*')
        Set plus = plus + 1
    End Repeat  

    Set row = row + 1

    Display a new line
End Repeat
```

Stop

**My code:**

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int main() {

    const int numRows = 7;
    const int maxPlus = 7;
    int numSpaces;
    int numPluses;
    int row;
    int space;
    int plus;

    row = 1;

    while((row >=1) && (row <= numRows)){
        numPluses = 2 * row - 1;
        if(numPluses > maxPlus){
            numPluses = 14 - numPluses;
        }
        numSpaces = (maxPlus - numPluses)/ 2;
        space = 1;
        while((space >= 1) && (space <= numSpaces)){
           cout << " ";
           space++;
        }
        while((plus >= 1) && (plus <= numPluses)){
            cout << "*";
            plus++;
        }
        row++;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

My question is why am I not getting the diamond pattern? I feel like I translated the algorithm correctly, but all I get is a bunch of blank space. Did I read the problem wrong or did I code wrong? [screenshot of C++ code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9b8X.png)

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? In addition, you don't seem to initialize `plus``, but you are reading it - your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Turn on all warnings. For example, "plus" is not initialized.

Comment: Compiler Warnings may not halt building of a program, but they are your first line of defense against trivial logic errors. Do not ignore them.

Comment: Also, consider turning your while loops into for loops. E.g. `for ( int plus = 1; plus >= 1 && plus <= numPluses; ++plus ) { ... }`

Answer (score 6):

Before the last while loop:

> ```
> Set plus = 1
> ```

You missed that in your translation.

Answer (score 1):

The code did not initialize `plus`.

There's a habit that saves much grief. Never declare a variable without giving it a meaningful initial value at the point of definition. Limit the scope of variables to where they are actually used. When translating pseudo-code, that can mean doing a little bit of re-writing.  Diggit.

```
int main() {
    const int numRows = 7;
    const int maxPlus = 7;
    for (int row = 1; row <= numRows; ++row) {
        const int trianglePluses = 2 * row - 1;
        const int numPluses = trianglePluses <= maxPlus 
            ? trianglePluses 
            : 2 * numRows - trianglePluses;
        const int numSpaces = (maxPlus - numPluses) / 2;
        for(int space=1; space <= numSpaces; ++space) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int plus = 1; plus <= numPluses; ++plus) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```