# Even-numbered rows not displaying properly, while odd-numbered rows do

Tags: c++, for-loop

Background and issue:

I have created a diamond shape program for class, but I'm having issues with an even amount  of rows for the diamond. I'm thinking there may be something wrong with my logic. It seems to be whenever I use an even amount of rows for the diamond shape, it does not show up as an even amount of rows but odd.

[image: Here's an example]

I've tried different possible "solutions", but they didn't work.

For example, I changed `for (int b = 0; b < asterisk; b++)` to for `(int b = 0; b <= asterisk; b++)` It displayed the correct number of rows, however it was no longer much of a proper diamond shape. It also (obviously) affected the odd-numbered row diamonds so they don't look like proper diamonds either.

[image: Example of the above]

I'm completely stuck and would definitely appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i, j, space, asterisk;

    do
    {

        cout << "Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): ";
        cin >> i;

        j = (i - 1) / 2;

        for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
        {
            space = abs(j - z);

            asterisk = i - 2 * space;

            for (int a = 0; a < space; a++)
                cout << " ";
            for (int b = 0; b < asterisk; b++)
                cout << "*";
            for (int c = 0; c < space; c++)
                cout << " ";

            cout << endl;
        }
    } while (i > 0);

    cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;

}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the insightful link, it's much appreciated. I did try to go step-by-step with my code.

Here's what I did:

    step 1: we input 4, to get 4 rows of a diamond shape.
    step 2: j = (4-1) / 2 = 1.5
    step 3: space = abs(1.5-0)
   space = 1.5
   step 4: asterisk = 4 - 2 * 1.5
asterisk = 1


This means that it should've added an asterisk but it didn't seem to do so at the bottom, which is for some reason blank? I did notice that on odd-numbered rows that it's returning a blank row at the bottom.

Comment: @Nite `j` cannot equal `1.5`.  `j` is an integer.

Comment: What is it that you are expecting when you enter `4` or `even number` ?

Comment: @MilesBudnek Apologies, 1.

Comment: @ShashankSingh This is what I'm expecting: https://i.imgur.com/mpVFzzd.png

Comment: A class mate of yours posted a question about the diamond thingy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695730/translating-algorithm-for-c-nested-while-loop-diamond-pattern/48696706#48696706

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i, j, space, asterisk, is_even;

    do
    {

        cout << "Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): ";
        cin >> i;

        is_even = (i % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        //Above line uses ternary operator to assign is_even flag to 1 if the number is even and 0 if it is not.
        j = (i - 1) / 2;

        for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
        {
            space =  abs(j - z);

            asterisk = (is_even) ? i - 2 * space - 1  : i - 2 * space; //Change 1

            for (int a = 0; a < space; a++)
                cout << " ";

            //Change 2.STARTS
            if(space == 0 && is_even ){
                for (int b = 0; b < asterisk; b++)
                    cout << "*";
                cout<<endl;
            }
            //Change 2.ENDS
            for (int b = 0; b < asterisk; b++)
                cout << "*";

            //for (int c = 0; c < space; c++)
            //    cout << " ";
            //You dont need to add the spaces at the end of each line.

            cout << endl;
        }
    } while (i > 0);

    cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;

}
```

Output ::

```
Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 1
*
Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 2
*
*

Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 3
 *
***
 *
Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 4
 *
***
***
 *

Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 5
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 6
  *
 ***
*****
*****
 ***
  *

Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 7
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 8
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
*******
 *****
  ***
   *

Enter the number of rows desired to make a diamond pattern (0 to quit): 0
Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if else statement after getting the input from the user. Then you can make a decision based on that input for how you would want to display your diamond.

Pseudo code:

```
{
    if ( odd ) {
        // do it this way
    } else { // even 
        // do it this way
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I was thinking about this earlier, but decided to not do it. I ended up doing it and it's working, however I think my logic is still flawed for even rows. I need to figure that one out now. I just changed the `for (int b = 0; b <= asterisk; b++)` line to be `<=` instead of `<`. Here is what it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/Pjt12pP.png

Comment: @Nite The problem is the alignment between even & odd amounts.

Comment: So I'm going to assume that the logic for even will not work at all then? Is it possible I may need to re-write it all? I can't think of anything that I can change that could possibly fix it. I've fiddled with just about everything that I can think of.

Comment: @Nite Even if you are working with specific types of searches within a string of length `N` the same problem arises. The conditional check within a for loop is important because of both the odd & even cases. If you have inclusive `<=` the algorithm will not behave the same as exclusive `<`. Just something to think about.

Comment: I tried to debug the best I can and this is what I got: https://i.imgur.com/s2G3atq.png I noticed that during the first run for the even side I'm getting asterisk as 2 instead of 1 and in the end I'm getting 0. I'm not trying to figure out how to fix this. Also this was the for loop as: `for (int b = 0; b = asterisk; b++)` not how I changed it like I said in a previous comment.